# Visual Studio table properties enter long queries >32000 characters

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have a very long SQL query that I would like to use to create a table in my tabular model in the Visual Studio. I developed that query using SQL Server Management Studio. When I copy that query to Visual Studio it only copies it partially. It seems that Visual Studio doesn't allow queries longer than 32000 characters. What could I do?

Comment: Have you considered breaking your query down into smaller components? A query that size sounds like a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: there are multiple union all statements and overall easier to manage

Comment: Put each `union all` query into its own view.

Comment: What is your query actually trying to accomplish? It can (and SHOULD) probably be rewritten to be much shorter.